# What does ruby_executable_hooks do?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby and usually when I want to create an executable script I put shebang at the beginning of a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Looking through different other script I came across the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
```

So what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does the same thing as any other shebang does: it calls the program.

In this case, it calls the program `/usr/bin/env` and passes `ruby_executable_hooks` as an argument. `/usr/bin/env` is used in this case to perform a path lookup, so the argument `ruby_executable_hooks` is also a program somewhere on the search path.

In order to know what this program does, you will have to look in your search path for a program called `ruby_executable_hooks` and read its source code (assuming that it is a script), or otherwise you have to figure out where it came from. Chances are, it is from the [`executable-hooks`](https://github.com/rvm/executable-hooks) Gem, but it could be anything.